# No ClassCastException is thrown inside Java generics

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Below is the first Java generics I've ever written :

```
public class MyClass {

    public static <T> T castToAnotherType(Object param) {
        T ret = null;
        try {
            ret = (T) param;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.print("Exception inside castToAnotherType()");
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String obj = MyClass.castToAnotherType(new Object());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.print("Exception outside castToAnotherType()");
        }
    }

}
```

The result is *"Exception outside castToAnotherType()"*. Why did the exception not occur inside the generic method?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`T` is effectively erased during compilation. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type
>   checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To
>   implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>     Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>     therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety. Generate
>     bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
> - Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized
>     types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

So your `castToAnotherType` gets `T` erased into ca. the following:

```
public static Object castToAnotherType(Object param) {
    Object ret = null;
    try {
        ret = (Object) param;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.print("Exception inside castToAnotherType()");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Which does obviously not produce any `ClassCastException`.

`main(...)` is a different story, it results into the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String obj = (String) MyClass.castToAnotherType(new Object());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.print("Exception outside castToAnotherType()");
    }
}
```

Which produces the `ClassCastException` when trying to cast `Object` to `String`.

Please see the [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) part of the [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: It is much more complicated than I thought. I need to spend more time studying to fully understand this when I have time to. For now, do you have any suggestion how to fix it? For example: return `null` when `param` cannot be cast to type `T`?

Comment: @Livy This is another question, please ask it separately. In short, one of the methods would be to pass the `Class<T> targetClass` as an extra parameter. But I'd love to see other answers. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, since the compiler erases the generic type parameters, the casting inside the method is essentially equivalent to :

```
    Object ret = null;
    try {
        ret = (Object) param;
    } 
    ...
```

which is not a problem, regardless of what you pass to your method (since any Object can be cast to Object).

However, when you try to assign that Object to a String, in your main method, the `ClassCastException` occurs, since `Object` cannot be cast to a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

All the generic types are erased in the compiled code. As far as the compiled code is concerned, `castToAnotherType` just returns an `Object`. However, your `main` method tries to assign it to a `String`, and it is not a `String`, so that produces a `ClassCastException`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure

Answer (score 3):

This is because of generic type erasure,

```
       T ret = null;
       try {
            ret = (T) param;
...
```

is translated by compiler into

```
       Object ret = null;
       try {
            ret = (T) param;
...
```

Comment: Actually `ret = (Object) param;`.