# why i am able to create generics collection of one type using totally different type?

Tags: java, generics

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699731/no-classcastexception-is-thrown-inside-java-generics) Java checks generics types only at run time but the same post's answer mentions that

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time

I don't quite understand the answer there. Is the type check performed at compile time or at runtime?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Address[] ad= new Address[3];
    ArrayList<Address> arr= new ArrayList<Address>();
    Employe e=new Employe(4, "harish");
    Address a = new Address();
    a.setOffice("SEX");
    ad[0]=a;
    arr.add(a);
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Employe> c = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(arr);
    for(Employe em: c)System.out.println(e.getName());
    listimplementations v =new listimplementations();

}
```

From my code the `collection<Address>` is successfully added inside another `collection<Employe>` and I'm getting an error at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: collection.Address 
cannot be cast to collection.Employe
at collection.listimplementations.main(listimplementations.java:26)
```

only during the for loop retrieval.  I think this is because inside  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` uses Object Array to store elements irrespective of generics type `<Employe>`.

1. If `<Employe>` is effectively erased during compilation then how do generics provide ***tighter type checks at compile time*** ?
2. Why is a compilation error not thrown during compile time for adding `Address` type inside `Employe` type collection?

Comment: Because you're using raw types. Generic type checks are done at compile-time. But `arr` is a raw type: it doesn't have any generic type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: i changed the code, im still getting error please check if this is what you mentioned.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/2891664.

Comment: You're still using a raw type: `new CopyOnWriteArrayList(arr);` should be `new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(arr);` or `new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Address>(arr);`, or `new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Employe>(arr);`. None of them would then compile.

Comment: please write this as answer i shall accept it.

Comment: @amarnathharish if you are compiling on the command line, javac will tell you that you are using raw types, and suggest flags to add to see more verbose warnings; IDEs like eclipse or intellij will show warnings about raw types. Pay attention to warnings, they are there to help you!